# Program not reading the "double" input correctly

Tags: c, double

In this C program, if I enter b as the input, the program prints Enter correct input. If I enter b45 as the input, the program again prints Enter correct input. But, if I enter 45b, the program takes 45 as the input and proceeds normally.

If I enter 45b, the program should print Enter correct input, but it is not happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
{
double i;

printf ("Enter a number. \n");
while (scanf("%lf", &i) == 0)
{
    printf("Enter correct input. \n");
    fflush (stdin);
}

printf ("%lf\n", i);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `scanf("%lf", &i)` returns 0, the non-numeric input remains in `stdin`.  Code never consume that input, so the problem repeats.  `fflush (stdin);` is UB.

Comment: "If I enter 45b, the program should print Enter correct input," --> then continue reading input until `'\n'` and see if there is non-white space.

Comment: `scanf` is a deeply imperfect function.  It's especially poor at error handling.  My recommendation — I don't know if this will work for you — is that if you're using `scanf`, just don't worry about improper input.  If you want the ease of calling `scanf`, set aside the goal of being nice to your users if they type something wrong.  If you want to do a nice job of detecting and responding to improper input, that's a worthy goal — but the only reasonable way to achieve it is by using techniques other than `scanf`.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin/58884121#58884121) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading via `scanf()`, read a *line* of user input with `fgets(buf, ...)`, then use `strtof(buf, &endptr))` to assess if the the input was numeric and `endptr` to assess what is after the numeric text.